# Return values that relies on a value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I thought this would be pretty easy but for some reason, I can't wrap my head around it. Maybe I am tired. Anyway, I want to return a policy value that has a status code of 1 and 4. I have a simple query:

```
select policiesid, eDeliveryStatusCd
from UserPolicyHistory
where PoliciesID is not null
and eDeliveryStatusCd in (1,4)
order by policiesid
```

Results:
[image]

See the highlighted policiesid of 10241? I want only those to return because it has an edeliverystatuscd of 1 and 4. So I want a policiesid that has a status code of 1 and 4 to return only, ignoring the rest. I thought it should be pretty simple. I don't know why but I can't figure it out today. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `exists()`:

```
select policiesid, eDeliveryStatusCd
from UserPolicyHistory as t
where PoliciesID is not null
  and eDeliveryStatusCd in (1,4)
  and exists (
    select 1
    from UserPolicyHistory as i
    where i.policiesid = t.policiesid
      and i.eDeliveryStatusCd in (1,4)
      and i.eDeliveryStatusCd <> t.eDeliveryStatusCd
  )
order by policiesid
```

Comment: I like this one! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add `group by` and `having`:

```
select policiesid
from UserPolicyHistory
where PoliciesID is not null and eDeliveryStatusCd in (1, 4)
group by policiesid
having count(distinct eDeliveryStatusCd) = 2;
```

Comment: This makes the assumption that there is uniqueness on policiesid and eDeliveryStatusCd.

Comment: @MikeS . . . No, in fact, it does not make that assumption.  Do you know what `count(distinct)` does?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of the sql.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer works if the table is unique on policiesid, eDeliveryStatusCd. If not try:

```
select policiesid, count(*)
from (select distinct policiesid, eDeliveryStatusCd
    from UserPolicyHistory uph1
    where PoliciesID is not null
    and eDeliveryStatusCd in (1,4))
having count(*) > 2
```